# View Rows as columns in postgres SQL without using cross Tab as Cross Tab is provioing the excepted results

Tags: postgresql, postgres-crosstab

I am using Postgres 9.6. and  i have a result set like this:

```
employee Name|collegeName |  Date    |attendance
-------------|------------|----------|-----------
employee1    |college1    |2020-05-01| true
employee1    |college2    |2020-05-01| false
employee2    |college3    |2020-05-01| true
employee3    |college4    |2020-05-02| true
employee4    |college5    |2020-05-02| false
employee5    |college1    |2020-05-03| true
employee6    |college3    |2020-05-03| false
```

My desired result is as follows:

```
employee Name|collegeName | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-03
-------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------
employee1    |college1    | true       |            |
employee1    | college2   | false      |            | 
employee2    | college3   | true       |            |
employee3    | college4   |            | true       |
employee4    |college5    |            | false      |
employee5    | college1   |            |            | true
employee6    | college3   |            |            |false
```

tried using cross tab but couldn't get the desired Result. please help.

Comment: If you can try CrossTab (Pivot) feature then it can be easily solved. review the link https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)